# Pytest error: 'py.test' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: python-3.x, pytest, notepad++

I am trying to run the pytest file in cmd. I am using the command

```
py.test
```

as mentioned by you but I am receiving the error :

```
'py.test' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

I have also tried to run the code as "pytest" in my other device, but I am getting the error as:

```
ERROR: PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied.
```

I am using notepad++ and running it in cmd.

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure you have pytest installed (pip install pytest)
2. All test files and functions should have the "test_" prefix
3. cd to directory with tests and run pytest